How we can get mobile robot velocity in the map frame?
velocity of the robot in the odom frame can be seen using 'rostopic echo /odom' but I want to know the velocity of the robot in the map frame of reference. Is there any ROS tool that can help me to know the velocity of the robot directly in the map frame or do I have to write a custom node (if this is the case please help me to write the code). My project deadline is approaching quickly, and I'm stuck in the middle. I would appreciate your prompt assistance.

If you want to echo velocity just echo your velocity topic...
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
